# Unable to export my data to a CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have some data I am trying to push out to a CSV but it keeps failing.  Any advice?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ExportFile = "C:\T2\Test.csv"

$MacHeading = "Mac OS: "
$MACOS = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "MAC*"' -Properties OperatingSystem, CanonicalName | Select Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem
$MACOSCount = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "MAC*"' | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}

$MacHeading | Export-CSV -path $ExportFile -Append
$MACOS | Export-CSV -path $ExportFile -Append
$MACOSCount | Export-CSV -path $ExportFile -Append
```

My error message is:

> Export-CSV : Cannot append CSV content to the following file:
>   C:\T2\Test.csv. The appended object does not have a property that
>   corresponds to the following column: Mac OS: . To continue with
>   mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then retry  the
>   command. At C:\T2\Test.ps1:9 char:15
>   + $MacHeading | Export-CSV -path $ExportFile -Append
>   +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Mac OS: :String) [Export-Csv], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: Did you try adding the -Force parameter as the error message suggests?  If so, what were the results?

Comment: The results are:

#TYPE System.String
Length
8

These are the results after using the -force options. It appears to be descriptions or garbage data not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you can create a csv file manually it is usually cumbersome and you will have to match the column headers when you add data manually.

In your code above you start your csv by creating a csv file with one header\column 'mac os'. `macos` is an objects with various properties and it does not contain a header called 'mac os' so export-csv does not know where to send the data.

also you are missing the `-notypeinformation` switch to `export-csv` without which the csv will contain an additional unneeded header with object type

you can look at doing something like this:

```
$comps = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "MAC*"'  -Properties OperatingSystem, CanonicalName | 
      Select-Object @{N='MacHeading';e={'Mac OS'}},Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem 

$comps | 
 ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 0} -Process {$I++; $_ | Add-Member -Name ID -Value $i -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru} | 
  Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Brilliant Kiran. Thank you so much you were the first person to really give me an answer for this. I must have spent easily 6-7 hours researching it and you solved it in a few minutes. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$comps=Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*MAC*' } -Properties OperatingSystem,CanonicalName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go without the `$MacHeading` (which isn't terribly useful for a CSV), you could just do this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "MAC*"' -Properties OperatingSystem, CanonicalName | 
    Select Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem |
    Export-CSV -path $ExportFile -Append -NoTypeInformation
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "MAC*"' | 
    Measure-Object | %{$_.Count} | 
    Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding ASCII
```

The key is to use `Out-File` instead of `Out-CSV` for the items that won't really make a CSV.